# If..Else in thymeleaf within <li> tags for TagIt

Tags: spring, if-statement, thymeleaf, tag-it

I have a problem. I want to show the list of interests of a user (or an example when the user has none). I need to use li tags for my TAG-IT library to take care of them. That is a must!

So I did an IF in thymeleaf that I need to mix with a li tag in a div. It shows a bunch of bullets (list of interests) for TAG-IT library to show them as a users' tags. But when the users has no tags attached, I have another IF to the show the tag with a message.

I thought my solution should work but the result is that it shows the interests from the user, but also the one that should only be shown when the user is new (and has no interests registered yet). It is like the second IF is not working and is always shown.

```
<div id="interestDiv">
<ul id="interestList">
    <li th:if="${interest} != null" th:each="interest : ${profile.interests}" th:text="${interest.name}">ID data</li>
    <li th:if="${interest} == null" th:text="'add your interest here (example: music ! )'">ID data</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first `<li>` `each` statement will initialize `${interest}` variable and this variable will never be `null`. That means in this case you don't need `if` statement at all. If `${profile.interests}` will be empty there is will be nothing displayed.

In second `<li>` you don't have any initialization for `${interest}` variable. That means this variable always will be `null`. For make this `<li>` work right way, you should check if list of interests empty or not. Something like:

```
<ul id="interestList">
    <li th:each="interest : ${profile.interests}" th:text="${interest.name}">ID data</li>
    <li th:if="${profile.interests.isEmpty()}" th:text="'add your interest here (example: music ! )'">ID data</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks for your help. I still have a small bug the first time the user loggs in and there is no interest created. It gives me an error: EL1011E:(pos 18): Method call: Attempted to call method isEmpty() on null context object. But it does not happen the second time, even if the interest is still null. I do not understand. Thanks again.